# Overriding Grails config for plugins

Tags: grails, configuration, grails3

I am trying to figure out how to separate deployment specific config from my Grails 3 app. In Grails 2 I could setup a config location lookup which would load my dev specific config file. And in Grails 3 I have found that I can provide additional spring configs when running the app, i.e.:

```
./grailsw -Dspring.config.location=classpath:application.yml,file:///home/nigel/src/app/dev.yml run-app
```

However, this doesn't work if I'm using plugins, such as below, where it will just used the config in grails-app/conf/application.yml:

```
./grailsw -Dspring.config.location=classpath:application.yml,file:///home/nigel/src/app/dev.yml url-mappings-report
```

So my question is, how do I provide deployment/dev specific config files to grails so that it works with the grails plugins.

Answer (score 0):

For grails 3, you can use [external config](http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/external-config) plugin. And configure the config locations.

```
grails.config.locations = ["classpath:myconfig.groovy"]
```

Comment: Thanks, I can get this kind of working if I set the grails.config.locations parameter in the application.yml file, as opposed to passing it as a JVM parameter which would be the most flexible approach.
So, this leave me with the question, what is the variable substitution that I should be using to point to the project home directory? I've tried ${project.home} and ${grails.home} but neither work.
At a pinch I could use the classpath as suggested, but having "external" config on the classpath seems counterintuitive.

Comment: When running war, there's no project home directory, you shouldnt be using a project home directory, but rather a file in either class path, or in users home directory, or somewhere inside catalina base directory and all this is supported, read the docs of the plugin

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Grails 3 [external config](http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/external-config) plugin for this task.

This plugin mimics Grails 2 way of handling external configurations defined in `grails.config.locations`

**Steps:**

1. Add dependency to the `build.gradle`.
2. Create a new local config Groovy script and add the configutation you want to override.
3. Add the external configuration property in your `application.yml` or `application.groovy` and provide the path to your local config file within it.

That's it.